# How to determine path of exlorer.exe in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I need to determine the path of the original explorer.exe on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows in a C# project. What is the most reliable way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the environment variable "windir" as explorer.exe is located in there

```
string windir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
string explorerPath = windir + @"\explorer.exe";
```